# State-of-art graph partitioner

Tags: graph, partitioning

Is there any state-of-art tool/algorithm for graph 'edge-cut' partitioning?

And same question for 'vertex-cut' partitioning.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for approximate or exact solutions?

Comment: Codor, I'm looking for both of that.

Answer (score 1):

For vertex-cut partitioning, a popular and performant linear runtime heuristic is HDRF (**h**igh-**d**egree vertices **r**eplicated **f**irst). There is a [Github project](https://github.com/fabiopetroni/VGP) (Java implementation). This can be considered as state-of-the-art although there are a few newer vertex-cut projects (e.g.  [H-load](ftp://ftp.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pub/library/ncstrl.ustuttgart_fi/INPROC-2016-13/INPROC-2016-13.pdf)).

Answer (score 0):

for Edge-Cut I can introduce Kaffpa(http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/documents/kahip/)
and Metis(http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview)
and for disterbuted you can use Spinner (Spinner: Scalable Graph Partitioning for the Cloud)